TypeScript pass Undefined Values to Functions with string param
I have the following issue: I have this rawSrcPattern variable that could be a string or undefined. I had to explicitly add a check because the formatAdvancedMethodsPatternToUi function needs a string, and this TypeScript issue causes a runtime error. When I hover over it, it explicitly says const rawSrcPattern: string, and it ignores the undefined cases, and still allow me to pass it to the function regardless of it still could be undefined. Why would TypeScript fail to show the other possible value for the variable?
srcPattern.split('-')?.[index] should return undefined by default if el at index is no available..


const fn = (srcPattern: string[], index: number) {


// 1. SRC Pattern string[] data-data-data ... 
const rawSrcPattern: string | undefined = srcPattern.split('-')?.[index];

const formatAdvancedMethodsPatternToUi = (rawSrcPattern: string) = {
// fn logic
}

// the parameter rawSrcPattern must show an error but it is not.
const fromatedSrcPattern = formatAdvancedMethodsPatternToUi(rawSrcPattern);

// rest of the logic
}




Please provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see the same thing you're seeing. That means you should declare anything you're referring to (e.g., srcPattern and index). Presumably you're asking about --noUncheckedIndexedAccess or the like, but without a [mre] that's just conjecture.

split returns an array of string and there is always the string not split. So, indexing to [0] always returns string. If you index something else, there is a possibility that it returns undefined. But builtin array type indexing doesn't have undefined as a possible output because that can break a lot of people's code. Just check the array length yourself first or add coalease empty string "?? ''"

the string structure is data-data-data and index could be bigger than data after split

Why are you calling split() on an array of strings? There is no such method. And an arrow function needs an arrow. This is still not a [mre]. Please copy your code into an IDE, and look at it. If there are problems you're not asking about, or the problem you are asking about isn't present, then your code isn't a [mre] and you need to [edit] to make it one. Right now I'm still struggling to see the issue through the errors.

rawSrcPattern is a string array, not a string. First of all, split function should give you an error like : Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string[]'
const rawSrcPattern: string | undefined = srcPattern.split('-')?.[index];

should be modified to:
const rawSrcPattern: string | undefined = srcPattern.join("").split('-')?.[index];

